# css animations inside inline blocks

Tags: css, css-animations

I am currently building a template that will be the foundation on my new website and have reached the point of adding the animations and other 'special effects'. For  basis to my template I am using the Boilerplate h5bp template and my header element is built of inline-blocks thus -

```
<header>
            <div class="box" id="head-one">
                <h1>Your name here</h1>
                <h2>Click to call <a href="tel:your-phone-number">your-phone</a> or <a href="mailto:you@your-domain.what.where?subject=Message%20subject%20here&body=Some%20text%20to%20add%20to%20the%20message%20body.">Email Us</a></h2>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="accordion.html">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="boxs.html">Page 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="images.html">Page 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div><!-- close class box id head-one
            --><div class="box" id="head-two"><!--
            --><img id="logo-head" src="images/logo.svg" alt="Logo for your web site">
            </div><!-- close class box id head-two -->
        </header>
```

This is how I have done the css alignment (The colours being used are purely to highlight box sizes and alignments at this stage) -

```
header
    {
        border: 0.5em solid blue;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: justify;
        padding: 1em 0.5em 0em 0.5em;
        margin: 5px auto;
    }

nav,
ul.menu,
ul.menu li
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

#logo-head
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

div.box#head-two
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
        display: inline-block;
        animation:logo 5s linear 0.3s 3;
        -webkit-animation:logo 5s linear 0.3s 3;
    }

@keyframes logo
    {
        0%      {transform:rotate(0deg);}
        25%     {transform:rotate(90deg);}
        50%     {transform:rotate(180deg);}
        100%        {transform:rotate(360deg);}
    }

@-webkit-keyframes logo
    {
        0%      {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
        25%     {-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);}
        50%     {-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
        100%            {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
    }

div.box#head-one
    {
        width: 75%;
        text-align: center;
    }

header::after
    {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

header div.box#head-one::before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

However the animation is pushing the logo contained in 'header div.box#head-two' to the bottom of the header box instead of up on the right side, without the animation the logo sits nicely vertically aligned - middle and to the right of the rest of the header content.

How can I stop this basic animation from breaking my structure, this is an important problem for me to solve on this project as page layouts depend on the inline-block display value.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't stay to the right for me without the animation.  You are setting `div.box#head-two` to 100% width and not floating it.  If I add `float: left` to those 2 divs and make `div.box#head-two` 25% width it works.

```
div.box#head-two {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    animation:logo 5s linear 0.3s 3;
    -webkit-animation:logo 5s linear 0.3s 3;
}

div.box#head-one {
    width: 75%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ydEPG/

Comment: I can't believe I had missed that, must have spent to much time looking for the 'tricks' instead of the obvious. Thanks for you help!